# How to run a Symfony app without using the built-in server?

Tags: php, symfony, php-builtin-server

In the documentation is clearly explained how to run the built-in server to run a Symfony App.

Ok, all works well and i'm very happy, but:

How can i run a Symfony App without using the server but simply something like http://localhost/path/to/symfonyApp/web/app.php?

Here the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/web_server/built_in.html

Comment: you will save your self alot of time and headache if you use built in server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is also explained in docs:
[Configuring a Web Server](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this could help: [Install Symfony 2 with wamp](http://www.abelworld.com/symfony-2-4-wamp-windows-installation/)

Answer (score 0):

It's not too hard, if you're running a local server (Apache/wamp) and have PHP configured to it already. If you're on a windows machine you'll want to run it with a nice linux-esque terminal like [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).  You'll also want to have [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to automate a lot of your Symfony tasks.

Then just download Symfony and put it in your web facing folder (htdocs, www, whatever you call it) and configure it according to what you need.